# From a Pandas Dataframe, return specific column values based on grouping and largest values of other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given the following code:

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd 


# Data to lists. 
 data = [{'Student': 'Eric', 'Grade': 96, 'Class':'A'}, \
{'Student': 'Caden', 'Grade': 92, 'Class':'A'}, \
{'Student': 'Sam', 'Grade': 90, 'Class':'A'}, \
{'Student': 'Leon', 'Grade': 88, 'Class':'A'}, \
{'Student': 'Laura', 'Grade': 80, 'Class':'B'}, \
{'Student': 'Leann', 'Grade': 22, 'Class':'B'}, \
{'Student': 'Glen', 'Grade': 9, 'Class':'C'}, \
{'Student': 'Jack', 'Grade': 90, 'Class':'C'}, \
{'Student': 'Jill', 'Grade': 87, 'Class':'C'}, \
{'Student': 'Joe', 'Grade': 58, 'Class':'C'}, \
{'Student': 'Andrew', 'Grade': 48, 'Class':'D'}, \
{'Student': 'Travis', 'Grade': 39, 'Class':'E'}, \
{'Student': 'Henry', 'Grade': 23, 'Class':'E'}, \
{'Student': 'Chris', 'Grade': 19, 'Class':'E'}, \
{'Student': 'Jim', 'Grade': 1, 'Class':'E'}, \
{'Student': 'Sarah', 'Grade': 93, 'Class':'E'}, \
{'Student': 'Brit', 'Grade': 92, 'Class':'E'}, \
] 

# Creates DataFrame. 
 df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

 print(df.groupby('Class')['Grade'].nlargest(2))
```

From the dataframe, I would like to return the students' names with the top 2 grades out of each class. I would like to return two different versions of the results.

Version 1 would have all of the original columns:

[image]

And, Version 2 would only return the names:

[image]

Output (would prefer to have the aforementioned two versions):

[image]

Comment: post data as text, not images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: you grouped by the student, so you're grabbing each student's two best grades

Comment: Working on the text..   Each student only has one grade.  I am grabbing the two best grades from each class.

Comment: I am not 100% sure how to post terminal output.

Comment: I thought I grouped by 'class', not 'student'?

Comment: you did. i misread. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), then apply [`head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) to your `groupby` object

```
df_new = df.sort_values(['Class', 'Grade'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('Class').head(2)
```

[out]

```
  Class  Grade Student
0      A     96    Eric
1      A     92   Caden
4      B     80   Laura
5      B     22   Leann
7      C     90    Jack
8      C     87    Jill
10     D     48  Andrew
15     E     93   Sarah
16     E     92    Brit
```

If you need to filter for your version 2 output, just use:

```
df_new[['Student']]

   Student
0     Eric
1    Caden
4    Laura
5    Leann
7     Jack
8     Jill
10  Andrew
15   Sarah
16    Brit
```

Comment: Nice!  How can I just return the Student column?  Trying to insert "df[['Student']]" returns a class error.  But, I am assuming that inserting "df[['Student']]" strips out all of the other columns before the trailing commands are executed.

Comment: append `[['Student']]` onto the end of `... head(2)`

Comment: Oh geez, I didn't even see that part of the post "df_new[['Student']]".  Thanks!

Comment: @enter_display_name_here i only added it after you asked :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option replicating your process is:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Class')['Grade'].nlargest(2).index.get_level_values(1)]
```

---

```
   Class  Grade Student
0      A     96    Eric
1      A     92   Caden
4      B     80   Laura
5      B     22   Leann
7      C     90    Jack
8      C     87    Jill
10     D     48  Andrew
15     E     93   Sarah
16     E     92    Brit
```